# Three very clearly separated elements on a single line

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have three short bits of text that I want to put on a single line, in a centered way; more precisely:

I want the first bit to be "left justified", i.e. to start at the leftmost part of the line.
I want the last bit to be "right justified", i.e. to end at the rightmost part of the line.
Finally, I want the middle bit to be located at the center of the remaining space between the other two.

Of those three requirements, I only know how to implement the one for the last bit, by using `\hfill`:

`\centerline{Left Center \hfill Right}`

I tried toying with `\hfil` or the `tabular` environment to implement the other requirements but failed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are better solutions, but one based on your idea with `\centerline` is very easy:

```
\leftline{Left \hfill Center \hfill Right}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it works. But what do you mean exactly by "there are better solutions" ? What could be better than a very short code that works ? Something more reusable maybe

Comment: @user40960 For one line it is quick and simple. It doesn't require `\noindent`. In the  case of extensive usage I would prepare a macro with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent A\hfill B\hfill C

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]